# Retrieving events from a server for a website

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a website using Javascript and PHP.  The website has events like receiving a message or receiving a challenge etc and also events that occur at a specific time like the challenge expiring.

I want the user to be notified of these events when they happen so what would be the best way to do this?  Would it be javascript sending a request every second or so to check for events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at websockets. A good way to do this in PHP is with a library called "Ratchet":

http://socketo.me/

Unfortunately websockets don't have very good cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  I thought websockets are only in HTML5?

Comment: I just saw your update.  I want my website to be cross-browser compatible so what would be the best solution for that?

Comment: The Ratchet site talks about using a "Flash Polyfill" for older browsers. I can't provide any information on how that would work but I'm sure there are some articles out there about cross-browser websockets.